# Find area of shaded area in curve with range of values for $y$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

[image]

> The parabola  in the diagram has equation $y = 32 - 2x^2$
>
> The shaded area lies between the lines $y=14$ and $y=24$

Looking at the graph, I only need to find half the area and multiply by 2.

I can get my range of x values by setting $y = 32-2x^2$

$2x^2 = 32$

$x^2 = 16$

$x = \pm 4$

$2\int^{4}_0 32 - 2x^2 dx$

$2[32x - \frac{2x^3}3]^4_0$

I could find the whole area of half the parabola this way but I do not understand how to limit this to the y values this way.

Comment: Hint: The right half of the shaded region is a rectangle plus the region below $y=32-2x^2$, above $y=14$, from $x=2$ to $x=4$.

Answer (score 2):

Lets consider the region as follows:

[image]

As you said before, we need just one half and then multiply it by $2$. Indeed, $y=32-2x^2$ gives us $x^2=\frac{32-y}{2}$ and then $x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{32-y}{2}}$. We nned,here, just the $+$ sign since we considered the first part of $xy$ plane. Now you should work on the following integral:

$$\int_{14}^{24} x dy$$

Comment: I am confused about why it is $\int^{24}_{14}$ and not $\int^4_0$

Comment: Hello!  I've been hoping to reach you!  See: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-criticism-and-constructive-praise

Comment: @amWhy: I sent an email to yournaem@gmail but faild.

Comment: Check with me in the chat link I cited above. My *email* username is **not** `amWhy`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the inverse function, area can be computed wrt symmetry axis.

$$ x  = 32 -2 y^2 ,\,  Area = 2  \int_{14}^{24} x \, dy = 2  \int_{14}^{24}  (32 -2 y^2)  dy $$

Comment: $y=32-2x^2$ not $x=32-2y^2$, but integrating over $y$ is certainly one way to go.

Comment: Integration on  inverse function , integrating over $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the equation $32-2x^2=24$, resp., $=14$ for $x$ shows that the upper boundary intersects the parabola at $x=\pm2$, the lower boundary at $x=\pm3$. It follows that the total area is given by
$$A=2\left(2\cdot(24-14)+\int_2^3\bigl((32-2x^2)-14\bigr)\>dx\right)={152\over3}\ .$$

Comment: How do you know the upper boundary is $\pm 2$ and the lower boundary is $\pm 2$